# Traefik load balancing weight not working as per expectation

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, traefik

I have configured the following ingress for traefik but traefik is sending the entire traffic to app-blue-release.  Ideally it should send only 30% traffic to blue and 70% traffic to green, but it's not working as per expectation.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    traefik.frontend.entryPoints: http
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-weights: |-
      app-green-release: 70.0
      app-blue-release: 30.0
  creationTimestamp: 2019-06-04T06:00:37Z
  generation: 2
  labels:
    app: traefik-app
  name: traefik-app
  namespace: mynamespace
  resourceVersion: "645536328"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/mynamespace/ingresses/traefik-app
  uid: 4637377-747b-11e9-92ea-005056aeabf7
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mycompany2.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app-release
          servicePort: 8080
  - host: mycompany.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app-ui-release
          servicePort: 80
        path: /widget
      - backend:
          serviceName: app-green-release
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
      - backend:
          serviceName: app-blue-release
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

I am using following traffic version.
*traefik:v1.7.11-alpine*

Earlier when the weight was configured with 10 (for blue) and 90(for green) then it was working fine. But once we changed to 30 and 70 respectively then this problem is happening.

Anyone has faced such issue before. Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be followed by [traefik issue 4494](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/4494) (instead of your own [issue 4940](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/4940))

> the annotation `ingress.kubernetes.io/service-weights` has been added in [v1.7](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v170-2018-09-24), before the annotation was ignored.

However, [as of June 11th, 2019](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/4494#issuecomment-500892876), Damien Duportal (Træfik's Developer Advocate) adds:

> There is no known workaround for now.
>   We are working on this, but as the version 2.0 of Traefik is currently worked on, we have to wait :)

---

This comes from [PR 3112](https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/3112)

> Provides a new ingress annotation ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-weights which specifies a YAML-encoded, percentage-based weight distribution. With this annotation, we can do canary release by dynamically adjust the weight of ingress backends.

(called initially `ingress.kubernetes.io/percentage-weights` before being renamed `ingress.kubernetes.io/service-weights` in [commit 11f6079](https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/3112/commits/11f6079d4814192db745c1175b9729bf64069de5))

The issue is still pending.
Try first to upgrade to [v1.7.12-alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/traefik) to check that the issue does persist.

[The example](https://github.com/yue9944882/traefik/blob/11f6079d4814192db745c1175b9729bf64069de5/docs/configuration/backends/kubernetes.md#user-content-general-annotations) mentions:

```
service_backend1: 1% # Note that the field names must match service names referenced in the Ingress object.
service_backend2: 33.33%
service_backend3: 33.33% # Same as 33.33%, the percentage sign is optional
```

So in your case, do try:

```
  app-green-release: 70%
  app-blue-release: 30%
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the commit you have provided is already in the 1.7 branches.  This issue occurs intermittently  but this makes the traefik "Not so Reliable" for production operations.

Comment: @nagendra547 I understand this commit is already in the 1.7 branch: the idea was to illustrate from which commit this feature was comming from.

Comment: @nagendra547 But as I say in my answer, the issue is still pending: I will monitor it and report back here if I see any evolution.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your reply. I have also reported this issue is in traefik github. https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/4940. I guess you already replied on this.

Comment: @nagendra547 If you see at the first line of my answer, I did mention issue 4940 indeed.